# debugging c++ program with <set> containers

Tags: c++, debugging, set

The problem is to find all vowels all even words in a sentence share, in other words these vowels have to be met in any even word in the sentence.
But i when i enter for example: "ewedyua aiuye dswidje ieuayj eeee eeeui dajhdfjcne aodijsbfe".
I get: e i u 
but "e i" is expected as the last even word doesn't contain 'u' (I use " " just for separation here in the text and don't use them in the output)

The program:

```
int main(){
string str; 
char ch = ' '; 
set<char> strSet; 
set<char> resultSet;
set<char> tempSet;
int count = 1;
int i = 0;

cout << "Enter a line: ";
getline(cin, str);
str = delOverSpace(str); // delete excessive gaps<br>
do {
 ch = str.at(i);
 if(((count % 2) == 0) && (ch != ' ')){  // this is an even word and not a gap
  if(isVowel(upperToLower(ch)))  // this is a vowel
    tempSet.insert(upperToLower(ch));   
  }

  if (ch == ' ') {   // if we've passed through the word add inforamtion on it
   if(((count % 2) == 0) && (count / 2) == 1)
    strSet.insert(tempSet.begin(), tempSet.end());
   else if (((count % 2) == 0) && (count / 2) != 1){
    set_intersection(
     strSet.begin(),strSet.end(), tempSet.begin(), tempSet.end(),
     insert_iterator<set<char> >(resultSet, resultSet.begin())
    );

   strSet.clear();
   tempSet.clear();
   strSet.insert(resultSet.begin(), resultSet.end());
   resultSet.clear();
  }
  count++;
 }

 i++;
}while(ch != '.'); 

if (count == 2) cout << "Only one word was entered" << endl;
else if (strSet.empty()) cout << "No vowels were found" << endl;
else {

copy(strSet.begin(), strSet.end(), ostream_iterator<char>(cout, " ")); 
cout << endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: When stepping through code in a debugger it usually helps putting separate statements on separate lines, otherwise the debugger might seem to step over statements that are actually executed. I'm talking about your `if (...) cout << ...` lines. Those aren't so bad since you will see the output, but if those one-liners didn't contain output it's much harder to debug. Those lines are not wrong, they just make the debugging process a little harder.

Comment: i see, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try not to use one counter variable for multiple purposes.
For example you could use `count` for the current character count within the current word and `words` for word count.
In your example, you're making `count` work too hard.

Decide what you are counting. Do you want to count every character?
Or do you want to count the characters in the current word?

When incrementing a counter, try to put this next to the logic that needs it.
Eg, `i++` should go right after you've used it to get the next character.
And `count` should be incremented in the block that handles letters (ie not space, not dot). 
If the counters get too far away from what they are keeping track of, you can introduce bugs.

Move the space check up first and also check for end of sentence with `.`
Clear indentation helps to follow the code - I use 4 characters, but 2 or 3 is ok. 
1 character indents are hard to read.

Use blank lines to separate different chunks of logic.

You might want to add logic to handle punctuation like `,`, `?`, `!` etc.

When you're processing an input string which is separated into words, it's often easier to handle the end of input condition outside the loop.
In this case, the loop exits after it picks up the last letter.
If that is not a `.` then you'll have an unprocessed word sitting in `tempSet`.
You can try and anticipate this within the loop, but it seems more natural to exit the loop and check if there is anything left to process.

If you separate your logic into clearly separated blocks, you can set breakpoints inside each block.
You'll then know what situation you're handling. You can break inside end-of-word logic and check `tempSet` and `count`.
Are they what you expect? 
And in the `else` part you can check `ch` going in and verify that it is classified as a vowel properly.

```
int main() {

    string str; 
    char ch = ' '; 
    set<char> strSet; 
    set<char> tempSet;

    int count = 0, words = 0, i = 0;
    cout << "Enter a line: ";
    getline(cin, str);
    str = delOverSpace(str); // delete excessive gaps<br>

    while ( i < str.size() && ch != '.' ) {

        // Get next character
        ch = str.at(i);
        i++;

        if (ch == ' ' || ch == '.' ) {   // if we've passed through the word add inforamtion on it
            if( count > 0 && ((count % 2) == 0)) {
                 strSet.insert(tempSet.begin(), tempSet.end());
                 words++;
            }
            count = 0; // reset the char counter
            tempSet.clear();    // clear the temp vowel set
        }
        else {
            // letter - not a space or a dot, increase the character count
            count++;
            if(isVowel(upperToLower(ch)))  // this is a vowel
                tempSet.insert(upperToLower(ch));   
        }
    }
    // pick up any unprocessed word if we hit end of input without seeing '.'
    if (count > 0 && ((count % 2) == 0)) {
        strSet.insert(tempSet.begin(), tempSet.end());
        words++;
    }

    if (words == 0) 
        cout << "No words entered" << endl;
    else if (words == 1) 
        cout << "Only one word was entered" << endl;
    else if (strSet.empty()) 
        cout << "No vowels were found" << endl;
    else {
        copy(strSet.begin(), strSet.end(), ostream_iterator<char>(cout, " ")); 
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: John D, thanks a lot for your answer, that was really helpful